# C# Adding Comments with YouTube V3 API

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I am using C# and using the YouTube V3 API. I am trying to insert a comment into a Video however whenever I do I receive a exception of `"{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}"` This happens whenever I run anything similar to the above code:

```
public void AddComment()
{
    CommentThread commentToAdd = new CommentThread();
    commentToAdd.Snippet.IsPublic = true;
    commentToAdd.Snippet.TopLevelComment.Snippet.TextOriginal = "Test";
    commentToAdd.Snippet.VideoId = "kc-LBxBcyG8";
    commentToAdd.Snippet.TopLevelComment.Snippet.VideoId = "kc-LBxBcyG8";
    CommentThreadsResource.InsertRequest ins = JKYouTube.NewYouTubeService().CommentThreads.Insert(commentToAdd, "snippet");
    var insertedComment = ins.Execute();
}
```

I am comparing this to the google explorer and using the same properties and the explorer actually adds the comments where as my program just fails. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert

As soon as it reaches the second line of code of
`commentToAdd.Snippet.IsPublic = true;`

It will just error and continue for every line above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are using the setter on the `Snippet` object. Are you sure `Snippet` is not `null`?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies in the fact `Snippet` is `null`.

Taken from the [API link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert) that you have given, you need to first create a `CommentSnippet`.

In the example that Google has provided:

```
// Insert channel comment by omitting videoId.
// Create a comment snippet with text.
CommentSnippet commentSnippet = new CommentSnippet();
commentSnippet.setTextOriginal(text);
```

First, a `CommentSnippet` is created with some text and then we create a top level comment:

```
// Create a top-level comment with snippet.
Comment topLevelComment = new Comment();
topLevelComment.setSnippet(commentSnippet);
```

And then, you add your `topLevelComment` to the `CommentThreadSnippet`:

```
// Create a comment thread snippet with channelId and top-level
// comment.
CommentThreadSnippet commentThreadSnippet = new CommentThreadSnippet();
commentThreadSnippet.setChannelId(channelId);
commentThreadSnippet.setTopLevelComment(topLevelComment);
```

When finally you have your `CommentThreadSnippet`, you can add it to a `CommentThread`:

```
// Create a comment thread with snippet.
CommentThread commentThread = new CommentThread();
commentThread.setSnippet(commentThreadSnippet);
```

Following those steps should not give you a NRE

Comment: Please see other comment. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your help. Managed to complete it.

```
async Task AddVideoCommentAsync(string commentToAdd, string videoID)
    {
        CommentSnippet commentSnippet = new CommentSnippet();
        commentSnippet.TextOriginal = commentToAdd;

        Comment topLevelComment = new Comment();
        topLevelComment.Snippet = commentSnippet;

        CommentThreadSnippet commentThreadSnippet = new CommentThreadSnippet();
        commentThreadSnippet.VideoId = videoID;
        commentThreadSnippet.TopLevelComment = topLevelComment;

        CommentThread commentThread = new CommentThread();
        commentThread.Snippet = commentThreadSnippet;

        var youtubeService = await NewYouTubeService();
        CommentThreadsResource.InsertRequest insertComment = youtubeService.CommentThreads.Insert(commentThread, "snippet");

        await insertComment.ExecuteAsync();
    }
```

Comment: You basically just wrapped Nikola's answer in async / await. At least accept his answer and delete your other "answer".